# Castle Windsor Configuration Type Converter with Dictionary<string, string> property

Tags: configuration, castle-windsor, typeconverter

I have read the Castle Windsor Documentation for [Type Converters](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/typeconverters.html) and [passing dictionaries](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/trunk/usersguide/arrayslistsanddicts.html#dict), however I am getting an error that doesn't seem to be mentioned in the docs.

My configuration:

```
<parameters>
    <controllerTranslations>
        <list>
            <item>
                <areaName></areaName>
                <routeValue>MyRoute</routeValue>
                <translationTable>
                    <dictionary>
                        <entry key="en">MyRouteEn</entry>
                        <entry key="fr">MyRouteFr</entry>
                    </dictionary>
                </translationTable>
            </item>
            ....
        </list>
    </controllerTranslations>
</parameters>
```

My TypeConverter:

```
public override object PerformConversion(IConfiguration configuration, Type targetType)
{
    var converter = new Converter(configuration.Children, Context);
    var areaName = converter.Get<string>("areaName");
    var routeValue = converter.Get<string>("routeValue");
    var translationTable = converter.Get<Dictionary<string, string>>("translationTable");
    ...
}
```

I get the error, "You must provide a key for the dictionary entry" when the converter tries to get the dictionary.

Debugging the DictionaryConverter in Windsor, the actual expected schema is as follows, but this doesn't seem right. My test passes and no exception is thrown from Windsor:

```
<parameters>
    <controllerTranslations>
        <list>
            <item>
                <areaName></areaName>
                <routeValue>MyRoute</routeValue>
                <translationTable>
                    <dictionary key="en">
                        <entry>MyRouteEn</entry>
                    </dictionary>
                    <dictionary key="fr">
                        <entry>MyRouteFr</entry>
                    </dictionary>
                </translationTable>
            </item>
            ....
        </list>
    </controllerTranslations>
</parameters>
```

With some further testing I think I have found the correct way to implement this:

```
<parameters>
    <controllerTranslations>
        <list>
            <item>
                <areaName></areaName>
                <routeValue>MyRoute</routeValue>
                <translationTable type="System.Collections.IDictionary, mscorlib">
                    <entry key="en">MyRouteEn</entry>
                    <entry key="fr">MyRouteFr</entry>
                </translationTable>
            </item>
            ....
        </list>
    </controllerTranslations>
</parameters>
```

Comment: I have also tried defining the key/value type in the configuration as indicated in the documentation but I still get the same error.

Comment: You can see the project here: https://github.com/coryt/WindsorTypeConvert-Test

Comment: can you simplify it enough to fit in a single file? there seems to be a lot of unrelated stuff in there.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem. Ok, I've taken out a few things but the rest is there to recreate my problem. I basically want to use the xml configuration in "RoutingTranslations.config" to define a bunch of ITranslatableRouteValue's and pass it into the IRouteTranslationBuilder.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer updated question to show a solution. Something seems odd about it though.